# Solr replication bandwidth control

Tags: solr

Is there a way to limit the amount of network bandwidth Solr slaves use to download data from the master? It currently defaults to using all the bandwidth available and that causes problems for other applications. I'm using Solr v3.5.

Edit: I'm using Java based replication.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can set it using the command described in [SOLR-2099](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SOLR-2099) issue.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm not using rsync based replication. I'm using the Java implementation of index replication. Is there a way to set the bw limit there?